# How can I call a method that requires Graphics g when I can't instantiate a Graphics object since it as abstract?

Tags: java

I need to find the size of the font for spacing purposes and found this helpful: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html

However, i'm not sure how I can make this work out correctly.

```
public Dimension getFontSize(Graphics g, JLabel l){
   Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

   FontMetrics metrics = g2.getFontMetrics(titleFont);

   return new Dimension(metrics.stringWidth(l.getText()), metrics.getHeight());
```

I think I may have to take an alternate approach here but I'm not sure how to do that as I'm not clear on how exactly Graphics works. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can pass an instance of a subclass e.g. Graphics2D

Comment: @user: Please clarify as your comment confuses me.

Comment: @Hovercraft its the answer to the posts topic. It doesnt answet the real question but it answers the questions topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the font metrics for a component in the GUI, then you can directly get its FontMetrics off of the component by calling `getFontMetrics(Font font)` directly on it. Otherwise, if you're drawing to a BufferedImage, you can extract its Graphics object *before* it is rendered (or after) by calling `getGraphics()` on your BufferedImage.

```
public Dimension getFontSize(JLabel label){
   FontMetrics metrics = label.getFontMetrics(titleFont);
   return new Dimension(metrics.stringWidth(label.getText()), metrics.getHeight());
}
```

Whatever you do, don't call `getGraphics()` on your GUI components before they have been rendered as that will return null.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure why I was told that I needed Graphics to begin with. This is a much easier way of doing things.